# Event extraction : state of the art and some tool to download

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

What is the state of the art for Event extraction?

Is there any openly availble tool to download for Event Extraction?

Comment: there is a real lack of context in this question ? what kind of events ? in what kind of setup ? ... As it is, I would say it is too broad.

Comment: There is a general definition of "event" in NLP community: http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mausam/papers/kdd12.pdf
As apposed to description.